# Windows Remote Desktop Connection for just a single window (or a single program)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is it possible to have just one program running on the remote Windows machine appear in the local monitor, rather than the whole remote desktop?

I heard SeamlessRDP provides something like that but only for connecting from Linux to Windows. What should I use in the case of connecting from Windows to Windows?

Comment: Stephen Jennings has it right, use TS RemoteApp. You may be interested in a comparison on features in similar applications: http://jaysonrowe.com/2008/07/20/windows-server-2008-terminal-services-vs-citrix-xenapp-vs-2x-application-server/

Comment: Your link seems not to be correct, @ta.speot.is .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature offered by [Terminal Services RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844%28WS.10%29.aspx) on Windows Server 2008 and greater.  However, your system administrator needs to set this up and publish the app for you.

A poor man's implementation of this would be to run a remote desktop session in a smaller-than-fullscreen window, then maximize the app you want inside that.