# Windows: Is there something to see and remotely control single(!) windows on a remote PC?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is there something where I can see and control **single(!)** windows of PC1 on PC2 remotely. Basically like it is possible with X-Windows.

I am **not** talking / asking about

1. A software which displays the whole desktop remotely (like VNC, Windows RDP).
2. A X-windows server for windows, to connect to Linux.

The answer here ( [Windows Remote Desktop Connection for just a single window (or a single program)](https://superuser.com/questions/121354/windows-remote-desktop-connection-for-just-a-single-window-or-a-single-program) ) requires Windows Server 2008.

I need to run this on **two Windows 7 machines**. Example: PC1 shows three windows, and I transfer, see, and control window 2 on PC2.

-- Edit --

I have checked whether there is an X-Server for Windows <-> Windows. But there seems not to be one other than Unix <-> Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453/what-is-a-good-and-free-x-server-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

This *is* technically possible, several virtual machine software applications do something very similar to this right now.  My main PC is currently Windows 8, but I use VirtualBox to run Linux Mint and then use "Seamless Mode" to run the Linux terminal and Chrome browser windows on my Windows desktop.  I However, I havent seen any demand for exactly what you are asking for.  There are enterprise products from MS, Citrix, and VMWare (probably others, too) that virtualize applications, so they can be run from other machines regardless of OS or version, but that isnt what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, I think I have seen that feature with VMWare (not 100% sure), where I did run my browser in a VM but displayed it as "normal window". Since I cannot run my app in a VM I am looking for this particular feature - this question has been asked with no answer in the past, but maybe something has come up.